# Ubuntu installed through Wubi does not boot due to "NTFS: error 'prefix' is not set"

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, wubi

I installed Wubi on my Windows XP Professional SP3. So when I start the system I get the menu where I select OS to start: Windows or Ubuntu. When I select Ubuntu, I get to a black screen with message

> Try (hd0,0): NTFS: error "prefix" is not set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like problem was due to the *.iso wasn't burned on CD. WUBI should be installed from CD apparently.